# C operator precedence of operator && and ||

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{ 
    int a = -3, b = 2, c = 0, d;
    d = ++a || ++b && ++c;
    printf("%d %d %d %d", a, b, c, d);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of program is:

```
-2 2 0 1
```

Compiler is evaluating the OR (`||`) operator before AND (`&&`) but the AND (`&&`) operator comes before OR (`||`) in operator precedence.

Please do explain why this happens.

Comment: I reopened the question; the use of prefix increment in the example is well-defined (as opposed to those in the "dupe"). Please, don't vote-for-close before you have thought things through.

Comment: you might want to read up on [short-circuit behavior](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/201896/what-is-short-circuiting-in-c-like-languages) of logical `&&` and `||`

Answer (score 3):

Precisely because [`&&` has more precedence than `||`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), the statement:

```
d = ++a || ++b && ++c;
```

is equivalent to:

```
d = ++a || (++b && ++c);
```

Now, `++a` is evaluated and tested first (due to the rules of [evaluation order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order) for operator `||`). This ends up being `-2`.

Since it is non-zero, the result is true (`1`). Therefore, the other part of the expression (`++b && ++c`) is *not* evaluated, due to the shortcut mechanics of the `||` operator.

Consequently, `d` gets assigned `1`.

Comment: Shouldn't  ++b&&++c  be evaluated first ,since precedence of && is before ||

Comment: @OmkarKadam You mixed up the evaluation order (left to right in this example) and operator precedence ( && ties more than || ).

Comment: Why doesn't the expression in the braces get evaluated first (the &&)? As far as I know, the c compiler evaluates parenthesis before anything else. (i'm still new)

Comment: @SmarthBansal There is a special rule for `||` which specifies the left-hand side is evaluated first (and the right-hand side is not evaluated if the condition was already true, see [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_logical)). Please also see the links I provided with the answer.